# ZFS after disk failure: most of data seems to be intact, but how to extract?

Tags: data-recovery, zfs

I have a zpool after disk failure. Attempt to import it (even `zpool import -F -T 12855264 -R /mnt -f rpool`) yields errors

```
Dec  4 12:56:54 freebsd kernel: Solaris: WARNING: can't open objset 1035, error 5
Dec  4 12:56:54 freebsd ZFS[10155]: pool I/O failure, zpool=rpool error=97
Dec  4 12:56:54 freebsd ZFS[10159]: pool I/O failure, zpool=rpool error=97
Dec  4 12:56:54 freebsd ZFS[10163]: failed to load zpool rpool
```

zdb shows some data

```
Dataset mos [META], ID 0, cr_txg 4, 1.02G, 304 objects
Dataset rpool/samba [ZPL], ID 100, cr_txg 135431, 276K, 9 objects
Dataset rpool/ROOT/pve-1 [ZPL], ID 515, cr_txg 10, 4.85G, 74685 objects
Dataset rpool/ROOT [ZPL], ID 259, cr_txg 8, 96K, 7 objects
Dataset rpool/secure/vm-103-state-good [ZVOL], ID 661, cr_txg 2925304, 2.94G, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/secure/vm-101-disk-1 [ZVOL], ID 1441, cr_txg 1445964, 188G, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/secure/vm-104-disk-0@good [ZVOL], ID 1285, cr_txg 2925290, 83.1G, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/secure/vm-104-disk-0 [ZVOL], ID 413, cr_txg 222940, 84.7G, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/secure/vm-104-state-good [ZVOL], ID 173, cr_txg 2925283, 438M, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/secure/subvol-105-disk-0@good [ZPL], ID 521, cr_txg 2925300, 1.36G, 36077 objects
failed to hold dataset 'rpool/secure/subvol-105-disk-0': Input/output error
Dataset rpool/secure/vm-101-disk-2 [ZVOL], ID 942, cr_txg 1445966, 114G, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/secure/vm-103-disk-0@good [ZVOL], ID 1027, cr_txg 2925319, 18.1G, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/secure/vm-103-disk-0 [ZVOL], ID 431, cr_txg 916036, 59.6G, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/secure/vm-101-disk-0 [ZVOL], ID 448, cr_txg 1445962, 160K, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/secure/vm-107-disk-0 [ZVOL], ID 285, cr_txg 219462, 16.9G, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/secure/vm-101-disk-3 [ZVOL], ID 654, cr_txg 2329396, 83.1G, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/secure [ZPL], ID 145, cr_txg 90, 200K, 7 objects
Dataset rpool/data/vm-100-state-good [ZVOL], ID 394, cr_txg 1864406, 114M, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/data/vm-106-disk-0@good [ZVOL], ID 1287, cr_txg 3889962, 3.97G, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/data/vm-106-disk-0 [ZVOL], ID 781, cr_txg 1890481, 27.5G, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/data/vm-100-disk-0@good [ZVOL], ID 518, cr_txg 1864412, 88.5M, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/data/vm-100-disk-0 [ZVOL], ID 266, cr_txg 36631, 88.6M, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/data/vm-106-state-good [ZVOL], ID 668, cr_txg 3889956, 358M, 2 objects
Dataset rpool/data [ZPL], ID 387, cr_txg 9, 96K, 6 objects
Dataset rpool [ZPL], ID 54, cr_txg 1, 10.3G, 26 objects
MOS object 403 (bpobj) leaked
MOS object 522 (DSL deadlist map) leaked
MOS object 1032 (zap) leaked
MOS object 1033 (DSL props) leaked
MOS object 1034 (DSL directory child map) leaked
MOS object 1035 (zap) leaked
MOS object 1036 (DSL dataset snap map) leaked
MOS object 1038 (zap) leaked
Verified large_blocks feature refcount of 0 is correct
Verified large_dnode feature refcount of 0 is correct
Verified sha512 feature refcount of 0 is correct
Verified skein feature refcount of 0 is correct
userobj_accounting feature refcount mismatch: 7 consumers != 8 refcount
encryption feature refcount mismatch: 14 consumers != 15 refcount
project_quota feature refcount mismatch: 7 consumers != 8 refcount
```

and it seems to me that only one dataset is damaged.

So I have two questions:

1. dd reads all the disk fine, what causes the I/O failure?
2. How do I extract intact data? Some datasets are encrypted, so just read blocks is not enough

Comment: Consider moving the question to the Super User or the Server Fault forums. It might be more suitable in the server admin forum, unless there is some programming involved. Then Stack Overflow would be the right one.

Comment: `dd reads all the disk fine, what causes the I/O failure?` I think the I/O failure is produced by ZFS itself. It can get the bytes from the disk without problems, but because its metadata is corrupt, instead of giving you the wrong data it displays the I/O error. This is how it is supposed to be.

Comment: I watched a [video of a ZFS data recovery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7gQwypNMdk) which was quite fascinating. The author did this with the assistence of a recovery company though, and heavy programming and debugging skills are required. Basically they disabled a bunch of safeguards in ZFS and dumped their data (even though some blocks were corrupt) and were able to recover most of it. I myself am not expert enough to follow through this.

Comment: One idea. Can you try to use `-o readonly` when importing? The mentioned video above emphasizes how important is to use `-o readonly` when importing in recovery scenarios. maybe ZFS would let you through if you are just reading... fingers crossed

Comment: -o readonly did not help

Comment: I saw your post on the FreeBSD forums. Not much luck there either. :( You can ask in the IRC channel #zfs. Usually there are some helpful people around.

Answer (score 0):

```
sysctl vfs.zfs.spa.load_verify_metadata=0
sysctl vfs.zfs.spa.load_verify_data=0
zpool import -F -R /mnt -N -f -o readonly=on *yourpool*
```

And what can be saved will be saved.

(the solution is for FreeBSD. Linux/Solaris uses other ways to set libzfs options, mdb for Solaris, *different* systl-s for Linux)